# NSUserDefaults data is lost after enabling app groups

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I have created the user defaults with suite name in my project like below without enabling app groups in the Signing & capabilities.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.compnaynamehere.sharedata"];

// Storing the value here 
[defaults setValue:@"This is value1" forKey:@"key1"];
[defaults synchronize];

// Retrieving value here for key1
NSString *value = [defaults valueForKey:@"key1"];
NSLog(@"This data stored for key1 is : %@", value);
```

The data is stored successfully and got the logs while retrieving key1:

```
2021-05-14 16:35:34.031941+0530 demo[16478:224183] This data stored for key1 is : This is value1
```

So everything is good till now able to access the data correctly on app reinstall or going to view controller.

Now comes the problem where I enable the app groups for my project in **Signing & capabilities**  selected the name **group.com.compnaynamehere.sharedata** and reinstalled the app

When I tried to get the stored value in view controller or Applegate using the below code the user defaults data is lost getting **null**:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.compnaynamehere.sharedata"];

 // Retrieving value here for key1
NSString *value = [defaults valueForKey:@"key1"];

NSLog(@"This data stored for key1 is : %@", value);
```

Got the logs like this (null) data for key1 :

```
2021-05-14 16:36:24.174784+0530 demo[16512:225476] This data stored for key1 is : (null)
```

Please help me on this how to fix this issue?

Comment: please clarify after enabling App Groups where do you set the value for "key1" before trying to read it back?

Comment: The value is set in above code starting befor enabling the app group and accessing the same value after enabling the app groups but it gives a null

Comment: Creating an App Group creates a new shared container for storing these defaults so that they can be shared amongst app, widget extension, watch extension, etc.  So you'll need to set an initial value.

Comment: But the initial values are already stored in the same  suit initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.compnaynamehere.sharedata" I dont have access to them once I enabling app groups.do you know why can't we access them with same suit name ?

Comment: Have same glich after rewrite value in same groupID suite. on iOS 16